# How can i check if the table in oracle has garbage value in its some column/row?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table name_data. It gets data in it through automated process.
What i want to check is- if that table has any garbage value in it.
Consider the below scenario:

```
select name_id, name_elem3, name_elem4 from name_data where name_id='200012884';

This query gives this result:
Name_id      name_elem3      name_elem4
200012884   GENEVIï¿½VE       MARRTIN
```

Now in the above result. The data has garbage value "GENEVIï¿½VE"
i want a query or a script that can check the table for garbage value

Comment: what is the parameters?

Comment: You probably don't have garbage in your column but rather have set your locale wrongly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define garbage. If you are looking for special characters that Oracle regards as non-alnum ('¿' and '½' here), you can use this for instance:

```
select * 
from mytable
where regexp_like(name_elem3,'[^[:alnum:]]')
   or regexp_like(name_elem4,'[^[:alnum:]]');
```

Change the pattern according to your needs.

Another option is to use TRANSLATE to remove all desired characters and check if other characters remain:

```
select * 
from mytable
where length(translate(name_elem3, '¿ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789', '¿')) > 0
   or length(translate(name_elem4, '¿ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789', '¿')) > 0;
```

(You need the '¿' or any other special character with TRANSLATE here, because of Oracle's weird "empty string is null" thing, where the second string literal would be empty, hence null, hence "unknown", such that TRANSLATE would always result in "unknown" = NULL, too.)

Comment: I do not know much about regular expressions. Is this  '[^[:alnum:]]' expression is for only allowing alphanumeric characters.??

Comment: Then look them up or use the TRANSLATE solution. (Anyway, ^ means NOT here; [:alnum:] means alphanumeric. So we are saying: where the column value contains a non-alphanumeric character.)

Comment: select * 
from mytable
where length(translate(name_elem3, '¿ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789', '¿')) > 0
   or length(translate(name_elem4, '¿ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789', '¿')) > 0;                                                                                     Can u please u explain this query ??

Comment: -Thanks for explaining.

Comment: I did. TRANSLATE removes all desired characters from the column value, which is A-Z, a-z and 0-9 here. So either you end up with an empty string or with a string still containing some special characters. With LENGTH > 0 we find the strings that contain special characters hence.