# Exporting table from Oracle to .csv keeps hanging

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, export-to-csv

I am trying to export a table in Oracle 12 to a local .csv file. I have tried using both SQL Developer's export function and using the spool command in SQL itself.

The frustrating aspect is that sometimes it will work via the spool command, but usually hangs around 50% of the way through.

SQL Developer doesn't throw an error but remains appearing busy indefinitely - making the issue difficult to diagnose. The .csv not growing at all is the indication that it has failed (plus it should only take 2 mins in the first place).

The SQL I'm using to spool it is:

```
set colsep ";"
set termout off
set linesize 9999
set trimspool on
set heading on
set pagesize 0
set wrap off
set feedback off
set newpage 0
set arraysize 5000
spool 'C:\Users\me\my_file.csv'
select /*csv*/ * from PRICING_DATA_SET;
spool off
```

Any help appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: I would guess that some of your columns contains garbage values that cause this. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35719053/how-can-i-check-if-the-table-in-oracle-has-garbage-value-in-its-some-column-row) and [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1191435335912) . May be you will get some ideas ...

Comment: Does it complete if you leave it long enough? The CSV not growing doesn't necessarily indicate that it's broken; it could be writing small amounts of data but not enough to fill a buffer and trigger a write to disk, or not be finding any data to write for a while. (Is it possible you've repeatedly deleted and reinserted large amounts of data resulting in an abnormal high water mark, which can slow down full table scans across big gaps?). Or it could be a network issue, or some resource issue... Does `select count(*)` complete quickly? How about if you spool from SQL\*Plus or SQLcl instead?

Comment: select count(*) is very quick (.39s) and I have been regularly dropping and re-creating it rather than deleting and inserting. To be fair I give up after about 20mins - I'm put off because it has occasionally worked and when it does its 2-3 mins. I will try and be more patient though!

Comment: I'm not sure about with SQL Developer, but I've had TOAD crash while spooling a large file. It seems to run out of memory trying to store the entire output for display. SQL*Plus has been much more reliable.

Comment: By _using the spool command in SQL itself_, do you mean the SQL*Plus command line tool, or SQL Developer? SQL has no `spool` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set colsep ";" -- no need to do this with /*csv*/
set termout off
set linesize 9999 
set trimspool on
set heading on
set pagesize 0 
set wrap off
set feedback off
set newpage 0
set arraysize 5000 -- don't do this
spool 'C:\Users\me\my_file.csv'
```

I'd just set feedback off.

Then

set sqlformat csv
spool file.csv
select * from table;
spool off

But don't do this in SQLDev GUI, use the command line interface, SQLcl - it's in the bin directory and works just like SQL*Plus.

You don't say how many rows it spits out, if any, before 'hanging.' You also don't say how big that table is.

So add a rownum < 50000 to your query and see how that goes. You may need to add memory to the JVM, but you really shouldn't need to

Comment: Thanks for this. The table is 1.7m rows but I was struggling to get more than 1m out. It seems that adding memory to the JVM has worked for the moment so thanks for the suggestion

Comment: That's a LOT of rows, big file. A 'fatter' JVM definitely makes sense there.

Answer (score 0):

In SQLPlus, just do

```
set markup CSV
```